# Sorting and reorganizing a CSV file as a python dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, data-manipulation

I have a csv file in the following format:

```
ComponentID subComponent    Measurement
X030        A1111111        784.26
X030        A2222222        784.26
X015        A1111111        997.35
X015        A2222222        997.35
X015        A3333333        997.35
X075        A1111111        673.2
X075        A2222222        673.2
X075        A3333333        673.2
X090        A1111111        1003.2
X090        A2222222        1003.2
X090        A3333333        1003.2
X105        A1111111        34.37
X105        A2222222        34.37
X105        A3333333        34.37
X105        A4444444        34.37
```

I'd like to return the file as a python dictionary of the following format:

```
my_dict = {'X030': ['A1111111', 'A2222222', 784.26],
           'X015': ['A1111111', 'A2222222', 'A3333333', 997.35 ],
           'X075': ['A1111111', 'A2222222', 'A3333333', 673.2],
           'X090': ['A1111111', 'A2222222', 'A3333333', 1003.2],
           'X105': ['A1111111', 'A2222222', 'A3333333', 'A4444444', 34.37]
          }
```

Initially, I was looking at it using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) but that didn't get me anywhere. My confusion is on how to design it as I'm not sure of how to return the following item: `ComponentID: [components, and only one measurement]`

I am not sure on how to go about this task, any guidance is appreciated

Comment: I guess you are at least sure on what is the underlying logic in here, right? Since you did not share any code, at least you could share the intended algorithm for this.

Comment: @fedorqui the dictionary will feed an external class that uses it to do some calculations and reporting.

Comment: I am not asking "how are you going to use it" but "how would you design it". Presented like this, it looks like a job assignment, whereas this is supposed to be a place in which you show what you've tried so far and where you are stuck in. Give a read to https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: @fedorqui Sorry about that, Initially, I was looking at it using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) but that didn't get me anywhere. My confusion is on how to design it actually. I'm not sure of how to return ComponentID: [ components, and only one measurement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having some trouble understanding the data structure to begin with: is it guaranteed that all subComponents of any given ComponentID will have the same Measurement? If so, then neither the given TSV format nor your desired dict is a very reasonable data structure for storing this information.

Nonetheless, here is some simple code that does exactly what you're asking:

```
d = {}
with open('yourfile.tsv') as tsvfile:
  next(tsvfile)
  for line in tsvfile:
    row = line.split()
    componentid, subcomponent, measurement = row[0], row[1], float(row[2])
    if not componentid in d:
      d[componentid] = [subcomponent, measurement]
    else:
      assert measurement == d[componentid][-1]
      d[componentid] = d[componentid][:-1] + [subcomponent, measurement]
```

And here is some code that puts it in a somewhat more logical structure:

```
d = {}
with open('yourfile.tsv') as tsvfile:
  next(tsvfile)
  for line in tsvfile:
    row = line.split()
    componentid, subcomponent, measurement = row[0], row[1], float(row[2])
    if not componentid in d:
      d[componentid] = {'subcomponents': [subcomponent], 'measurement': measurement}
    else:
      assert measurement == d[componentid]['measurement']
      d[componentid]['subcomponents'] += [subcomponent]
```

which gives you

```
{
  'X105': {'measurement': 34.37, 'subcomponents': ['A1111111', 'A2222222', 'A3333333', 'A4444444']},
  'X015': {'measurement': 997.35, 'subcomponents': ['A1111111', 'A2222222', 'A3333333']},
  'X075': {'measurement': 673.2, 'subcomponents': ['A1111111', 'A2222222', 'A3333333']},
  'X030': {'measurement': 784.26, 'subcomponents': ['A1111111', 'A2222222']},
  'X090': {'measurement': 1003.2, 'subcomponents': ['A1111111', 'A2222222', 'A3333333']}
}
```

Comment: I modified your code and made the following function that solved my problem: /def data_from_csv(csv_file):.
    `d = {}
    with open(csv_file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            componentid, subcomponent, measurement = row[0], row[1], float(row[2])
            if not componentid in d:
                d[componentid] = [subcomponent, measurement]
            else:
                assert measurement == d[componentid][-1]
                d[componentid] = d[componentid][:-1] + [subcomponent, measurement]
    return d`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your `csv` rows and use `dict.setdefault` method to store your rows in a dictionary :

```
>>> import csv
>>> d={}
>>> with open('your_file.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         d.setdefault(row[0],[]).extend(row[1:])
...     print d
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be:

```
myData = {}
with open('p.csv') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        if ('ComponentID' not in line):
            row = [x.strip() for x in line.split('        ')]
            cid = row[0]
            sub = row[1]
            msmt = row[2]

            if cid in myData.keys():
                msmt = myData[cid][-1]
                myData[cid] = myData[cid][:-1]
                myData[cid].append(sub)
                myData[cid].append(msmt)
            else:
                myData[cid] = row[1:]
print myData
```